# how to get a div with javascript "this" keyword

Tags: javascript

I will give you a snippet to show you what I want to achieve and what I got instead.

```js
function myfunc(){
    var qwertyui = this.innerHTML;
     document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = qwertyui;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myfunc(this)"/>
            <div id="mydiv"></div>
```

I wanted to get the `innerHTML` of the input through the JavaScript "this" keyword, but now it tells me undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You need to accept the element as the parameter. Furthermore, you should get the `value` of the input to obtain what the user entered, as opposed to its `innerHTML`.

```js
function myfunc(elem){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = elem.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myfunc(this)"/>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```